# C# Custom Invoke method to invoke various other methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delay, invoke

I have various methods that work fine, but I want to call them only after a delay. To avoid writing a different method for *all of them* I figured it's more beneficial to `Invoke` them somehow. I made the methods so that they exclude `Unity`'s `timeScale`, so they always wait for `Real seconds`, using a custom built short function.

The `WaitForRealSeconds`:

```
public class WaitForRealSecondsClass
{
    #region Wait for real seconds

    public Coroutine WaitForRealSeconds(float aTime, MonoBehaviour mono)
    {
        return mono.StartCoroutine(_WaitForRealSeconds(aTime));
    }
    private IEnumerator _WaitForRealSeconds(float aTime)
    {
        while (aTime > 0.0f)
        {
            aTime -= Mathf.Clamp(Time.unscaledDeltaTime, 0, 0.2f);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The way I wish to `Invoke` a `Move function` of mine:

```
public void InvokeAnim(float timeBeforeStart, Action<MonoBehaviour> MoveFunction, MonoBehaviour mono)
{
    if (moveRoutine != null)
    {
        mono.StopCoroutine(moveRoutine);
    }
    moveRoutine = _InvokeAnim(timeBeforeStart, MoveFunction, mono);
}
IEnumerator _InvokeAnim(float timeBeforeStart, Action<MonoBehaviour> MoveFunction, MonoBehaviour mono)
{
    yield return new WaitForRealSecondsClass().WaitForRealSeconds(timeBeforeStart, mono);
    MoveFunction(mono);
}
```

And the `Move(MonoBehaviour mono)` itself:

```
public void Move(MonoBehaviour mono)
{
    if (moveRoutine != null)
    {
        mono.StopCoroutine(moveRoutine);
    }
    moveRoutine = _Move(from, to, overTime, mono);
    mono.StartCoroutine(moveRoutine);
}
```

What I tested and worked is the `Move` itself, the `WaitForRealSeconds` I used in another project for UI waiting when the game was stopped, it was fine then. 
As I said I have many methods to invoke, all of them return `void` and have a parameter `MonoBehaviour`. Currently it doesn't do anything and I have no idea why.

Comment: That's all great but .. There's already this `public void Invoke(string methodName, float time);` method within **Unity API** so you can just call it like `Invoke("MeFancyMethodName", 0.5);` and `MeFancyMethodName` will be called after `0.5` second delay.

Comment: Yes, but I **have to** pass that `Monobehaviour` because these methods are not descendants of that. AFAIK `Invoke("Name", time)` can invoke only `void Name()` methods.
**Edit:**
And they cannot be `MonoBehaviours` because I needed the power of inheritance to make these methods happen.

Comment: Yes that's correct. But still you can make a _"wrapper"_ around that will invoke method which then will invoke your method with parameter that was previously specified. It'll be much easier than making it from scratch :)

Comment: True, but I didn't feel like implementing some `Inception` :D At least I learned something new by writing this and it works now.

Comment: @m.rogalski In terms of performance, OP is doing fine. Unity's Invoke method uses reflection so I think coroutine is best way to go. You will notice the performance hit with many GameObjects.

Comment: @Programmer Thank you for the explanation. It was something that I didn't knew till now :)

Comment: @Programmer I didn't know that either, googling "reflection" now :D 
I just heard somewhere that "coroutines are your friends, use them as often as possible" and I mindlessly took them to heart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sod it, I was dump enough to forget **actually Starting that coroutine.**

In my `Invoke`:

```
        public void InvokeAnim(float timeBeforeStart, Action<MonoBehaviour> MoveFunction,
        MonoBehaviour mono)
    {
        if (moveRoutine != null)
        {
            mono.StopCoroutine(moveRoutine);
        }
        moveRoutine = _InvokeAnim(timeBeforeStart, MoveFunction, mono);
        mono.StartCoroutine(moveRoutine); //one line was missing
    }
    IEnumerator _InvokeAnim(float timeBeforeStart, Action<MonoBehaviour> MoveFunction,
        MonoBehaviour mono)
    {
        yield return new WaitForRealSecondsClass().WaitForRealSeconds(timeBeforeStart, mono);
        MoveFunction(mono);
    }
```